# Random Function from SQL Server database in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, t-sql

I am creating a webpage which is using asp .net as its backend.  I need to grab categories from my database which is SQL Server.  I am using this code right now

```
For Each row00 As DataRow In f_oDatatable(7).Rows
  sCategories += row00.Item("Category").ToString & " / "
Next

If sCategories.Length > 0 Then 
   sCategories = sCategories.Substring(0, sCategories.LastIndexOf(" / "))

CType(Me.FindControl("dbcategories"), HtmlGenericControl).InnerHtml = "Categories: " & sCategories
```

This code works great and outputs my categories correctly.  But what I need to do is have the categories output randomly.  (i.e: "one/ two/ three/ four/ five" - and then another time - "two/ five/ one/ three/ four")

I can not have it create a random string in the database b/c of other dependencies for the categories to be the same every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Did you mean ASP .NET is used as the frontend?

Comment: Well I am using ASP .NET to run my website...therefore I am programming using Visual Studio 2008 and my pages are written (i.e. home.aspx, home.aspx.vb)  What I need is code written for home.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably load the datatable with a command that's something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORY
```

If so, this will return them in random order:

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORY ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: @egrunin your method worked absolutely perfect.  I can't ask for anything better than adding two words.  Thanks so much! - I would give you an upvote...but I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Answer (score 0):

in your first for loop, instead of concatenating to sCategories, add each category name a collection of your choosing. shuffle the entries with the Fisher-Yates algorithm, then loop through your collection to build the final string.

edit: a previous revision of the wiki page for the shuffle has a vb.net implementation. here you go.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle&diff=347101177&oldid=347084753

more edits: for a small number of options (5 qualifies), make a new table and store every permutation of those 5 names in it. when the time comes, pick a random row.

Comment: I am not the most experienced ASP .NET programmer but there has to be an easier way than this.  Maybe I should have specified that at most I will only have 5 categories.  Therefore i <= 5.